# Error with 'ostream' and 'istream' in C++ trying to overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

When modifying a `TAD` with`templates` to make it generic (add templates):

For input / output data I have this code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matrix & m)
{
  os << m.rows() << " " << m.columns() << std::endl;
  os << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed;
  for(int i=1; i <= m.rows(); i++)
  {
    for(int j=1; j <= m.columns(); j++)
    {
      os << m.value(i,j) << " ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
  }

  return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Matrix& m)
{
  int rows, columns;
  float v;

  is >> rows >> columns;
  for (int i=1; i<=rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j=1; j<=columns; j++)
    {
      is >> v;
      m.assign(i,j,v);
    }
  }

  return is;
}
```

The definition (summary):

```
#ifndef MATRIX_HPP
#define MATRIX_HPP

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename E, int R, int C>
class Matriz
{
public:
  Matrix();
private:
  E elements_[R][C];
};
#include "matrix.cpp"
#include "matrix_io.cpp"

#endif // MATRIX_HPP
```

The implementation (summary):

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>

template<typename E, int R, int C>
Matrix<E,R,C>::Matrix()
{
  for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<C; j++)
    {
      elements_[i][j] = 0; 
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
#include "matrix.hpp"

#define Element float

#define MatrixP Matrix<Element, 3, 3>

void tryBuildMatrix()
{
  MatrixP m;
  std::cout << m;
}
```

**This error:**

> error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}'
>   lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'    std::cout << m;

Any idea why it occurs?

PS: if I remove the `template` the code is perfect.

Comment: Your overloaded operators need to be template functions too, or instances of some template.

Comment: Like the matrix class? `template<typename T>
std<T>::istream& operator>>`

Comment: Yes, your operators take plain "Matrix" arguments.  Tell me where you define those?  Nowhere.  You need to use the same template definitions to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<typename E, int R, int C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Matrix<E, R, C> & m)
{
...
}
```

Comment: that gives me another error: ` undefined reference to `Matrix<float, 3, 3>::columns()'`

Comment: I hope you declared your custom operators after you declared your Matrix class... The flow above does not do that, but your code might be different.  And, I see no definition of rows() or columns() methods.

Comment: If you want i can edit the question to put all the code

Comment: im not really new here _stack overflow spanish :)_